# Undefined index error upon $em->clear() in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, unit-of-work, undefined-index, memory-limit

I have written a Symfony command to import some data from an API. It works but the problem is my PHP memory usage increases when I insert a big JSON in my database. And my unitOfWork increases by '2' to after each activty import.

I have already unset all my used objects, and I have read the documentation of Symfony2 when you want to do massive batch: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html

But when I use `$em->clear()` my entity manager gives this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: 000000007b56ea7100000000e366c259 in  path-to-application\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 2228

Here is my complete code :

```
 /**
 * @see Command
 */
protected function configure() {
  $this
    ->setName('ks:user:runkeepersync')
    ->setDescription('Synchroniser les activités d\'un utilisateur runkeeper')
    ->setDefinition(array(
      new InputArgument('access_token', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Access token'),
    ))
}

/**
 * @see Command
 */
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
  $accessToken = $input->getArgument('access_token');
  $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
  $UserHasServices = $em->getRepository('KsUserBundle:UserHasServices')->findOneByToken($accessToken);
  if (!is_object($UserHasServices) ) {
    echo "Impossible de trouver l'utilisateur qui possède le jeton ".$accessToken."";
  }
  $user    = $UserHasServices->getUser();
  $service = $UserHasServices->getService();
  echo "avant de requérir l'api : ".memory_get_usage()."\n";
  try {
    $rkApi = $this->getContainer()->get('ks_user.runkeeper');
    $rkApi->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    $activities  = $rkApi->getFitnessActivities(0,25);
    $nbParPages  = 25;
    $nomberActivitites = $activities->size;
    $aActivities = $activities->items;
    $nbPages =  floor ($nomberActivitites/$nbParPages);
    $aEndurance = array("Running", "Cycling", "Mountain Biking", "Walking", "Hiking", "Downhill Skiing", "Cross-Country Skiing", "Snowboarding", "Skating","Wheelchair", "Rowing", "Elliptical", "Other");
    $aEnduranceUnderWater = array("Swimming");
    $enduranceOnEarthType = $em->getRepository('KsActivityBundle:SportType')->findOneByLabel("endurance");
    if (!is_object($enduranceOnEarthType) ) {
      echo "Impossible de trouver le type de sport d'endurance";
    }
    $enduranceUnderWaterType = $em->getRepository('KsActivityBundle:SportType')->findOneByLabel("endurance_under_water");
    if (!is_object($enduranceUnderWaterType) ) {
      echo "Impossible de trouver le type de sport d'endurance sous l'eau ";
    }
    echo "Après avoir récupéré 25 activités : ".memory_get_usage()."\n";
    $a = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<=$nbPages;$i++){
      if($i!=0){
        $activities  = $rkApi->getFitnessActivities($i,25);
        $aActivities = $activities->items;
      }
      foreach ($aActivities as $activity) {
        $a = $a+1;
        $codeSport = $this->formatNameSport($activity->type);
        $sport = $em->getRepository('KsActivityBundle:Sport')->findOneByCodeSport($codeSport);
        if (!is_object($sport) ) {
          $sport = new \Ks\ActivityBundle\Entity\Sport();
          $sport->setLabel($codeSport);
          $sport->setCodeSport($codeSport);
          $sport->setSportType($enduranceOnEarthType);
          $em->persist($sport);
          $em->flush();
        }
        $activityDetail = json_decode($rkApi->requestJSONHealthGraph($activity->uri));
        if(in_array($activity->type, $aEndurance)){
          $urlActivitieDetail = $activityDetail->activity;
          $ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth = new \Ks\ActivityBundle\Entity\ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth($user);
          isset($activity->total_distance)? $ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth->setDistance($activity->total_distance) : "";
          isset($activity->duration)? $ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth->setDuration($this->secondesToTimeDuration($activity->duration)) : "";
          isset($activity->start_time)?  $ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth->setIssuedAt(new \DateTime($activity->start_time)) : "";
          $ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth->setModifiedAt(new \DateTime('Now'));
          $ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth->setSport($sport);
          isset($activityDetail->total_calories)?  $ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth->setCalories($activityDetail->total_calories) : "";
          isset($activityDetail->climb)?  $ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth->setElevationGain($activityDetail->climb) : "";
          $maxElevation = 0;
          $minElevation = 10000;
          if(isset($activityDetail->path)){
            foreach($activityDetail->path as $gpsPoint){
              if($gpsPoint->altitude > $maxElevation){
                $maxElevation = $gpsPoint->altitude;
              }
              if($gpsPoint->altitude < $minElevation){
                $minElevation = $gpsPoint->altitude;
              }
            }
            $ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth->setElevationMin($minElevation);
            $ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth->setElevationMax($maxElevation);
          }
          $em->persist($ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth);
          $em->flush();
          //Pour chaque activité on a un identifiant relatif au service qu'on synchronise
          $ActivityComeFromService = new \Ks\ActivityBundle\Entity\ActivityComeFromService();
          $ActivityComeFromService->setActivity($ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth);
          $ActivityComeFromService->setService($service);
          $ActivityComeFromService->setIdWebsiteActivityService($activity->uri);
          $ActivityComeFromService->setSourceDetailsActivity($rkApi->requestJSONHealthGraph($activity->uri));
          $ActivityComeFromService->setTypeSource("JSON");
          $em->persist($ActivityComeFromService);
          $em->flush();
          echo "Import de l'activite num ".$a." type :".$activity->type." effectue avec success \n";
          unset($ActivitySessionEnduranceOnEarth);
          unset($ActivityComeFromService);
          echo "UnitOFWOrk -> ".$em->getUnitOfWork()->size()."\n";
        }
        if(in_array($activity->type, $aEnduranceUnderWater)){
          $ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater = new \Ks\ActivityBundle\Entity\ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater($user);
          isset($activity->total_distance)? $ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater->setDistance($activity->total_distance) : "";
          isset($activity->duration)? $ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater->setDuration($this->secondesToTimeDuration($activity->duration)) : "";
          isset($activity->start_time) && !empty($activity->start_time)?  $ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater->setIssuedAt(new \DateTime($activity->start_time)) : "";
          $ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater->setModifiedAt(new \DateTime('Now'));
          $ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater->setSport($sport);
          isset($activityDetail->total_calories)?  $ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater->setCalories($activityDetail->total_calories) : "";
          isset($activityDetail->notes)?  $ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater->setDescription($activityDetail->notes) : "";
          $em->persist($ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater);
          $em->flush();
          $ActivityComeFromService = new \Ks\ActivityBundle\Entity\ActivityComeFromService();
          $ActivityComeFromService->setActivity($ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater);
          $ActivityComeFromService->setService($service);
          $ActivityComeFromService->setIdWebsiteActivityService($activity->uri);
          $ActivityComeFromService->setSourceDetailsActivity($rkApi->requestJSONHealthGraph($activity->uri));
          $ActivityComeFromService->setTypeSource("JSON");
          $em->persist($ActivityComeFromService);
          $em->flush();
          echo "Import de l'activité num ".$a." type :".$activity->type." effectué avec succès\n";
          unset($ActivitySessionEnduranceUnderWater);
          unset($ActivityComeFromService);
        }
        echo "Après chaque activité : ".memory_get_usage()."\n";
        unset($sport);
        unset($activityDetail);
        $em->clear();
      }
    }
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw $e;
  }
}
```

Thanks, @AdrienBrault. I have tested with `--env=prod --no-debug`, and it is true that it consumes less memory, but the memory still increase. How can I really clear the entity manager? and stabilize the memory?

Comment: The first step to decrease memory usage on commands is to run them on the prod environment and with debug disabled : `php app/console command --env=prod --no-debug`

Comment: Thanks, @AdrienBrault I have tested with --env=prod --no-debug, and it is true that it consumes less memory, but the memory still increase ... How can i do to really clear the entity manager ? and stabilize the memory ?

Comment: @Hosh, why not add a comment under the answer you do not like, explaining why it is not a good solution? They may be willing to offer further help or advice.

Comment: My bad, allow me to explain. My problem with the current answer is it's not a fix, it's a workaround. I don't see the need to reset the manager. There's clearly a different issue going on that is breaking Doctrine. While resetting this (if it works at all, I've not tried it) is fine as a workaround, it's not a fix. Anyway, doing this in production sounds like a really bad idea. Hope that makes things clearer!

Comment: try to remove usage of ```unset``` from your code.

Answer (score 10):

Symfony logs all SQL queries in dev environment, so first you need to disable it

```
// disable logger
$em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
```

You may use event listeners on entities, it may also increase memory usage. You can disable them like so

```
// remove all listeners
foreach ($em->getEventManager()->getListeners() as $event => $listeners) {
    foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
        $em->getEventManager()->removeEventListener($event, $listener);
    }
}
```

Remove `unset` from your code, there is no need for them, as you clear entity manager every step of your loop.

```
// save and clear
$em->flush();
$em->getUnitOfWork()->clear();
```

Remember that doctrine can optimize your queries, and improve perfomance if you group queries into one `flush`. So the best practice would be to execute `flush` once over some parts of your data. For example:

```
// collect 100 entities and then save them
if (($i % 100) == 0) {
    $em->flush();
    $em->getUnitOfWork()->clear();
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly the solution. But your solution led me to the solution. It turns out one of the event listeners I was overriding (by overloading the class parameter for it) was doing something that caused this. Having removed that definition (and manually only removing that event listener) solved this issue. I will give you the bounty.

Comment: How did you get rid of "undefined index" ? And can you write code for the extended solution you talked about ?

Comment: also with getUntiOfWork instead of the plain clear call i get the undefined index - Anybody come up with a real solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the entity manager with:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->resetEntityManager();
```

and then:

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
```