# Detecting an entity mis-configuration in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Well, I don't know what to do to fix a bug in my project.

I'm trying to handle a nested form with a many-to-many-with-attribute relationship.
The errors says it cannot create the association because an ID is required for one of the side.

Alright. So I tried to create just the missing side.
But still the same error.

Finally, I realized that I had still the same problem with this simple code :

```
public function onSuccess(Page $page)
{   
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

I would appreciate to have an error message such as "hey, there's nothing to flush!"
But no, still the same error : I have to create the object (and its id) prior to associate it.

I had a look to the stack trace. And yes, it seems that UnitOfWork ->computeAssociationChanges is called after the flush, and requires Ids for associated objects.

How can I create the objects in the database if the flush command generates a bug ?

Comment: What id generation strategy are you using?  Section 4.8 in the Doctrine 2 manual.  If it is auto then you need not do anything special on flushing.  If you are using a manual strategy then you need to create the id before flushing.  Might consider creating a command object and testing out your model without going through all the form processing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and sorry to reply so late...). Most of my tables are id-generated in auto. There is just one table which is not. This is the table holding the attribute of the many-to-many relationship. Therefore, it only has the two ids of each side, and the attribute. I agree that I need to have both IDs first in order to build this relationship. What is a command object ? And how could I use it to test the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was due to a maj misspell in an entity class.
I found it by checking the schema structure, using an add-on to Symfony:

```
<?php
namespace Lp\LibBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\DoctrineCommandHelper;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ValidateSchemaCommand;

class MyValidateSchemaCommand extends ValidateSchemaCommand
{

/**
 * (non-PHPdoc)
 * @see Tools/Console/Command/Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command.ValidateSchemaCommand::configure()
 * 
 * Modifies name of the command to be in Doctrine namespace
 * Adds the Helper em for the entity manager which is not defined in Doctrine class 
 * @author ulrich, 09/09/11
 */
protected function configure()
{
    parent::configure();
    $this->setName('doctrine:orm:validate-schema');
    $this->addOption('em', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The entity manager to use for this command');
}

/**
 * (non-PHPdoc)
 * @see Tools/Console/Command/Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command.ValidateSchemaCommand::execute()
 * 
 * Ajoute le Helper em pour l'entity manager qui n'est pas définis dans la class Doctrine
 * @author ulrich, 09/09/11
 */
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    DoctrineCommandHelper::setApplicationEntityManager($this->getApplication(), $input->getOption('em'));

            return parent::execute($input, $output);
}
```

[Source: Ulrich](http://www.mon-code.net/article/26/ajouter-les-lignes-de-commande-doctrine2-a-symfony2)

This allowed to use this command instruction to detect the entity misspell.

```
> php app/console doctrine:orm:validate-schema
```