# Flush error in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony-2.1

Quite a long time since I try to handle many-to many relationships with attribute.

I re-checked the entities, the forms... Everything looks ok. Still get an error :

The relationship is built like this: Book > OneToMany > AuthorBook < ManyToOne < Author

Nested forms allow to create books, from which authors are created with a year attribute..

So far, I'm only trying to record new authors, in order to make them exist before handling a relationship with a book.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($book->getAuthorBooks() as $authorBook) {
   $AuthorUrlname = $this->mu->generateUrlname( $authorBook->getAuthor()->getFirstname().'-'.$authorBook->getAuthor()->getLastname() );

   // If the author does not exist yet, it is added to the database:

   $checkAuthor = $this->em->getRepository('cmdMyBundle:Author')->findOneByUrlname($AuthorUrlname);

   if ($checkAuthor == null) {                  
        // Author does not exist
        $newAuthor = new Author();
        $newAuthor->setLastname($authorBook->getAuthor()->getLastname());
        $newAuthor->setFirstname($authorBook->getAuthor()->getFirstname());
        $newAuthor->setUrlname($AuthorUrlname);
        $newAuthor->setCollection($this->collection);
        $this->em->persist($newAuthor);
        $this->em->flush();

    }else{
        // Author already exists
    }

}// foreach $authorBook
```

And the error:
A new entity was found through the relationship 'cmd\MyBundle\Entity\Book#authorBooks' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: cmd\MyBundle\Entity\authorBook@0000000002571fc4000000002c4ddfaa.

Why is the error related to authorBooks relationship ? My code only tries to record a new author...

Thanks

EDIT_____________

Indeed, I made further tests, and a drastic one with this code :

```
public function onSuccess(Page $page){   
    $this->em->flush();
```

This also generates the same error, as if the error was not due to the form processing code...
I validated the orm schema using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186812/detecting-an-entity-miss-configuration-in-symfony2), and so far everything looks good.

I tried to cascade persist the entities :

```
class AuthorBook
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="cmd\MyBundle\Entity\Author", inversedBy="authorBooks", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $author;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="cmd\MyBundle\Entity\Book", inversedBy="authorBooks", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $book;
```

--

```
class Book
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="cmd\MyBundle\Entity\AuthorBook", mappedBy="book", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $authorBooks;
```

--

```
class Author
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="cmd\MyBundle\Entity\AuthorBook", mappedBy="author", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $authorBooks;
```

This updates the error message:

> Entity of type AuthorBook has identity through a foreign entity
>   Author, however this entity has no ientity itself. You have to call
>   EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure it an
>   identifier was generated before trying to persist 'AuthorBook'. In
>   case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or
>   PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush()
>   between both persist operations.

I understand I need to persist and flush books and authors before AuthorBook. However, I can't flush anything. I even have this error when I don't persist anything.

Comment: I think the error it's referring to the Entity field is not configured as `cascade={"persist"}`, take a look [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to configure the association with cascade persisting. However, this does not fix the bug. I edit the question as I discovered further clues...

Comment: Can you add details about entities and relationships? Can you also explain in which line the error is thrown?

Comment: I was just editing the post :) But the error is not located...

Comment: "I understand I need to persist and flush books and authors before AuthorBook. ".  This is not correct.  The entity manager will take care of persisting things in the correct order.  It's hard to tell what is going on from your posted code.  I'd suggest making a command object and working through your persist process without the complication of forms.

Comment: Actually, this is my problem. I don't know what to do to understand what's going in with the persist/flush process... But I don't know what is a command object and how to use it. Is there any resource I could read for this ?

Comment: The cookbook is a truely wonderful resource: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html And then of course there is the Doctrine 2 manual: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your class `AuthorBook`. Remove `@ORM\Id` for both `$author` and `$book` and add a correct id field. You should have had an error message when updating your schema, but in case you didn't:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force;
```

Update `AuthorBook` to this:

```
class AuthorBook
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="cmd\MyBundle\Entity\Author", inversedBy="authorBooks", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="cmd\MyBundle\Entity\Book", inversedBy="authorBooks", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $book;
```

Comment: I remember to have tried this solution before, whith no success. It is necessary to delete the authorbook from the database first in order to bypass ids conflicts when updating schema. So I tried this again, I have an other error message due to a data required to perform a book insertion in the database. I have to make further tests ; I'll try to remove cascadings. But your answer may be the point...

Comment: I had to struggle with entities cascade persisting, but this is it!  Problem solved! Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have any more column in AuthorBook (only foreign keys) I could try to do a manytomany relationship.

Url: [Many-to-Many Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

Comment: Indeed, I simplified the post, but there is one more column, that is the attribute of the relationship...